# Why do things look smaller when farther away?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometry

Here is my question:
Take an object A and another object B, both of the same size.

B is rigid (static)  but A is mobile . If I  took A further away from observer then it goes on shrinking. Why is that the case ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why railroad tracks seem to converge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202251/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188070/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/242509/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you wonder why when an object is far away it seems smaller?

This can be explained with basic trigonometry.

[image]

In this triangle, let say your object A has a height given by the distance $h=HF$

If we call the distance between your eyes and the object $d=EF$

Then the height that you see is linked to the angle at the corner $E$. Let's call that angle $\theta$.

Then, you have $\theta=arctan(h/d)$

As d gets bigger, the angle $\theta$ will decrease and it will seem that the objects is shrinking.

Comment: http://bit.ly/22W7ep9   shows a 27 second clip from a TV show called Father Ted, explaining the same point about cows.